# What is it and what is the nature of scalar quantity?

Tags: energy, particle-physics

Well, the question is philosophically speaking about what scalar quantity is in essence. If we take the case of a vector, it is clearly defined intuitively, but when it comes to scalar quantities, it is noticeable that it is something much more vague for the mind to understand, since there is an absence of visual analogy. We don't see energy, time, temperature, for example, and moreover they are quantities of a completely different nature, in principle by common sense, but we still use the same concept of scalar quantity to define them. In the case of temperature, trying to understand by analogy, I always thought of the particles in motion of a system as vectors associated with their vibrations and translations between themselves, in which the effects of their sum would result in the scalar energy of that system. So, in general, I associate the scalar quantities as a sum of random and chaotic vectors that exert influence within a given space or set, but this way of thinking would no longer make sense in the case of time and mass, for example, then, in my ignorance, to conclude why things of completely different natures correlate with the same concept, I come to think that in a micro view all these quantities are made by particles that orbit the quantum world and have similar properties, in such a way that it makes sense to encompass them as scalar energy. So, what is it and what is the nature of scalar  quantities?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> We don't see energy, time, temperature, for example ...

Examples of scalar quantities that you can see are the length of an object or the distance between two objects. In fact, every vector quantity in physics has an associated scalar quantity - its magnitude. So scalars are, in one sense, more fundamental than vectors.

Measuring time essentially comes down to counting - counting the beats of a pendulum or the oscillations of a crystal for example. And number is another scalar quantity - the number of apples in my bag is a very simple and intuitive scalar quantity. In fact, it is an even simpler scalar quantity than length or distance, because it is dimensionless.

Answer (score 1):

Objects in physics are scalars (resp. vectors, spinors, or tensors) *under a group* $G$ if they transform like a scalar (resp. vector, spinor, or tensor) under a scalar (resp. vector, spinor, or tensor) representation of $G$. For example, if $G$ is the Lorentz group (group of boosts and rotations), a quantity $x$ is a scalar if
$$S(g)xS(g^{-1}) = x,$$
where $S(g)$ is a scalar representation of the Lorentz group. $x^\mu$ is a vector if
$$\Lambda(g)x^\mu \Lambda(g^{-1}) = {\Lambda^\mu}_\nu x^\nu,$$
and so on. Two important points: (1) A scalar under one group $G$ might transform non-trivially under a different group $G'$. (2) An object with indices is not necessarily a tensor; it must satisfy the correct transformation laws.

Comment: Can you indicate me a study material, book on the subject? It was already a good orientation of what is happening, but it is still obscure.

Comment: I would recommend taking a look at any advanced book on mechanics which introduces tensors (Landau and Lifshitz is a nice one in my opinion).